# Spotfire - Custom expression on two tables

Tags: expression, spotfire, tibco

I have two tables, one that contain some vehicles with their height, and the other one that contain limits for each category of vehicle.

I want to display, in a bar chart, the number of vehicle that are out of height limit, for each category. For that I need a custom expression.

I tried something but it doesn't work because there are two tables, it works well when there is only one table. For technical reasons, I can't have only one table. Here is my attempt:

```
sum(If([VEHICLE].[height]>[HEIGHT_LIMIT].[hlimit],1,0) OVER (Intersect([VEHICLE].[category]))
```

With this I get the following error:

> All arguments of the function '>' in the expression must be aggregating when the visualization combines data from different tables.

---

Here is a little data sample:

```
VEHICLE TABLE
category | id | height
---------+----+------
   A     |  1 |  1
   A     |  2 |  3
   A     |  3 |  3
   A     |  4 |  4
   B     |  1 |  2
   B     |  2 |  4
   C     |  1 |  1
   C     |  2 |  1

HEIGHT_LIMIT TABLE
category |     hlimit
---------+----------------
   A     |       2
   B     |       3
```

---

With this data sample the bar chart should show 3 for category A, 1 for B and 0 for C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I want to admit that I've never made a custom expression that addresses more than one table.

My solution would be to insert the hlimit column to the vehicle table with a left outer join, and then create a calculated column that is 1 if hlimit is exceeded, and zero otherwise. Both tables would still remain in the application.

Comment: Sadly I can't have only one table for technical reasons because one table is generated with user input.

Comment: @txemsukr is there something preventing you from joining the tables in Spotfire?

Comment: @niko That would add some more complexity. I would have preferred to keep things as simple and maintainable as possible

Comment: in line with my virtual data table concept (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32089679/4419423), I recommend adding your two tables, then adding the primary table as a reference to itself, and finally inserting the column from the second table to that reference ("virtual") table.

Spotfire can of course handle cross-table expressions but I've found that they add weird quirks to the analysis. doing it this way is self-documenting and sustainable. you have to remember that Spotfire's expression language is not SQL and is not designed to behave as such. crossing tables is the complexity to avoid :)

Comment: @niko
Thanks, I thought it was better not to have redundancy of information between tables. I used SQL a lot and I thought the best way to do it was with a SQL approach. I was definitely wrong. I fixed my problem the way described in your answers.

Comment: glad you got it sorted! yeah it's definitely a shift to go from "SQL/database thinking" to "Spotfire thinking." step by step, though :)